# waf does not correctly detect C++ #include dependencies

Tags: waf

I have C++ header file dependencies that I specify in my waf script with the  `includes=...` parameter to bld.program().

I know the waf build configuration sees the includes because my program compiles correctly.

However, when I change a header file, waf does not detect the change. That is, when I run `waf build` after changing the contents of an included header, nothing gets recompiled.

Isn't waf supposed to determine #include "..." dependencies automatically?

How can I troubleshoot this?

I have looked in the build/c4che directory to see if I could make sense of the configuration files stored there. Mention of "include" in the waf generated .py files is suspiciously absent.

I am using waf version 1.9.0.

I have also tried this with waf 1.8.19 and got the same result.

EDIT: I replaced my original complicated wscript with the much simpler one listed below, and I still get the same behavior.

Here is my wscript:

```
top = '.'
out = 'build'
CXXFLAGS = ['-fopenmp', '-Wall', '-Werror', '-std=c++11', '-Wl,--no-as-needed']

def options(ctx):
    ctx.load('compiler_cxx')

def configure(ctx):
    ctx.load('compiler_cxx')
    ctx.env.CXXFLAGS = CXXFLAGS

def build(ctx):
    ctx.program(source="test_config_parser.cpp", target="test_config_parser", includes=["../include"], lib=['pthread', 'gomp'])
```

Comment: Not so much a c++ problem apparently. With straight GNU make build systems, the `-M<x>` option is used to generate header dependency files, that can be included by a Makefile.

Comment: My assertion is that it's a problem with waf, not C++. I don't want to generate dependencies in a Makefile using -MM, that's why I'm using waf.

Comment: I'm not yet sure why your example isn't working, I'm trying to see if the docs can shed any light. https://waf.io/book/#_include_processing

Comment: @jsp Is there anything weird about your includes, are they nested at all?

Comment: @leetNightshade No, I don't think so. wscript lives in ./tests. ./tests/test.cpp includes ./include/inc.h. ./include/inc.h includes only standard headers.

Comment: @jsp I mean in the C++ header, do you have any #if blah \n #include "inc.h" \n #endif or something like that. The docs at the link I included say it doesn't handle that. And it can't handle a few other weird uses.

Comment: @leetNightshade Good idea. I have standard include guards but no other preprocessor macros. If I remove the include guards, and rerun waf configure, it still does not work.  Changes to the header does not trigger a rebuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you use includes out of the project's directory. By default waf does not use external includes as dependencies (like system includes) to speed up things. Solutions I know of :

1/ 
Organize your project to have your include directory under the waf top directory :

```
top_dir/
    wscript
    include/
        myinclude.h
    sources/
         mysource.cpp
```

2/
Change top directory. I think `top = ..` should work (not tested).

3/
Tell waf to go absolute by adding this lines at the beginning of `build()`:

```
waflib.Tools.c_preproc.go_absolute=True
waflib.Tools.c_preproc.standard_includes=[]
```

4/
Use gcc dependencies by loading the gccdeps waf module.

Solution 1/ is probably the best.

By the way I prefer to have my build directory out of the source tree. Use `out = ../build` in your `wscript`, if you want to build out of the source tree.

my2c

Comment: Chapter 10.2.1 of the [waf book](https://waf.io/book/#_include_processing) clearly shows an example of a header being used that is not in the same directory as the source. I thought that was the purpose of the `includes` parameter to `bld.program()`. It says, "System include paths should be defined during the configuration and added to INCLUDES variables".

Comment: @jsp: yes. You can use includes out of your current source directory. What I said is that waf does not consider file outside of its top directory as checked dependencies by default. It's typically intended to ignore system includes dependencies. In the waf book example you quote, the '..' directory is the top directory, not outside of it. I edit my answer for clarity sake.

Comment: I get it now. I mistakenly thought waf would distinguish my includes from system includes just by virtue of being specified in the includes parameter to bld.program(). I've moved my wscript to the top level as you suggested in 1) and deps now work as expected.  Thanks for the clarification. I've accepted your answer.